# How to filter on column value in bash

Tags: bash, awk, filter, grep

I'm facing a problem while trying to `grep` (filter) a logfile on the value of an integer.

**logfile.log:**

```
2014-11-16 21:22:15 8 10.133.23.9 PROXIED ...
2014-11-16 21:22:15 1 163.104.40.133 authentication_failed DENIED ...
2014-11-16 21:22:15 15 163.104.40.134 authentication_failed DENIED ...
2014-11-16 21:22:16 9 163.104.124.209 PROXIED ...
```

I have an int in column 3 : `8`, `1`, `15`, `9`.

I need to grep only if: `value > 10`.

Something like:

```
cat logfile.log | grep {$2>10}
2014-11-16 21:22:15 15 163.104.40.134 authentication_failed DENIED ...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should make!

```
$ awk '$3>10' file
2014-11-16 21:22:15 15 163.104.40.134 authentication_failed DENIED ...
```

With `$3` we refer to the 3rd field, so that `$3>10` means: lines having 3rd field bigger than 10. If this is accomplished, the condition is true and hence `awk` performs its default behaviour: print the line.

You could of course say: print just an specific field, which you could by saying `awk '$3>10 {print $1}' file`, for example.

Comment: Simple and do the job !
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Through regex plus grep.

```
grep -P '^\S+\s+\S+\s+(?!0)(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|\d{3,})\b' file
```

I assumed that there isn't a decimal number in the column 3.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dY0jY0/1)

Comment: Works but the other solution is more simple by avoiding regex. Thank you!!

Comment: Yep, it's a solution through grep.

Comment: The filter (>10) is well this part: (?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|\d{3,}) ??
I wanted to change my filter from 10 to 1200, easy with awk but with a regex it's harder